# Unix Time para TDateTime

Tags: delphi, datetime, timestamp

preciso converter uma hora recebida em um json no formato **750382** para **00:12:41** no delphi tem a função **UnixToDateTime()** mais só funciona se eu receber a data e hora completa, mais neste caso só recebo a hora, a data e hora completa são 10 digitos, já tentei complementar os outros 4 digitos com a data atual mais também não dá certo, estou usando o site https://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html para verificar
alguém sabe como fazer neste caso? este valor é um tempo de duração em minutos...

Obrigado!

Comment: Isso ai não me parece UNIX Time

Answer (score 0):

Para criar uma data a partir do stamp (que suponho estar em segundos) podia fazer apenas

```
  dt:=incSecond(0,750382);
```

usando uma variavel dt do tipo TDatetime e a funçao IncSecond (unit DateUtils)

Porem o inicio das datas do delphi e das do unix sao diferentes, por isso penso que tem de usar o UnixDateDelta, que é a diferença inicial entre os 2 formatos

```
dt:=IncSecond(UnixDateDelta,750382);
```

Penso que assim já funciona (a mim deu uma hora a menos mas penso que pode ter a ver com o fuso horario, se é que isso faz sentido)

E já agora, usando o site que deu como referencia, esse stamp dá-me 09/01/1970, 17:26:22